# Dataset as array/list in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am new to tensorflow.
I want to directly inspect the contents of a dataset in tensorflow 2.0.
I believe that in tensorflow 2.1 one could do something like this:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3]) 
list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
```

How to do the same in tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3]) 
[d.numpy() for d in dataset]
```

Answer (score 0):

As eager-mode is activated by default in TF2.x, I prefer this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
dataset_it = iter(dataset)
print(dataset_it.__next__()) # output is generated by .numpy()
```